# Using Wordpress conditional is_page

Tags: wordpress, conditional-statements

I need help with using Wordpress conditional. The below code is the actual code I'm having problems with. 
The goal is to check if the page is "bb_press" and if it is, load another template called "archive-forum". 
If it's not, then continue using current template. 
I tried defining if is_bbpress in the beginning, but I'm not doing something right. Perhaps the ending is the problem.. 
Help appreciated

```
<?php
if ( is_bbpress() ) {
get_template_part('archive-forum') {
else {

<--- Continue with the current template code --->       

}
<?php endif;?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

After this, I'm getting a blank page with nothing loaded.

EDIT: This is the orignal template I'm trying to modify. Without your suggestions. Tried them, but I'm doing something wrong. What am I missing here? Am I placing the "if" in the wrong place? Thank you all for your help so far.

```
<?php
/**
* Directory archive page
*
**/
get_header(); //Header Portion
$tmpdata = get_option('templatic_settings');
global $posts,$htmlvar_name;

do_action('after_event_header');

/* Left content side bar for all pages */
global $htmlvar_name;
if(function_exists('tmpl_get_category_list_customfields')){
$htmlvar_name = tmpl_get_category_list_customfields(CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_EVENT);
}else{
global $htmlvar_name;
}
if (!is_active_sidebar( 'tmpl_listings_left_content') ){
$class="content-middle";
}else{
$class="";
}

/* Here we use for Show left content sidebar , it can be use for many other purpose too */
do_action('tmpl_all_pages_left_content');   
?>
<div class="content-sidebar <?php echo $class; ?>">

<script type="text/javascript">
var category_map = '<?php echo $tmpdata['category_map'];?>';
<?php if($_COOKIE['display_view']=='event_map' && $tmpdata['category_map']=='yes'):?>
jQuery(function() {         
jQuery('#listpagi').hide();
});
<?php endif;?>
</script>
<!--taxonomy  sidebar -->

<!--end taxonomy sidebar -->
<div class="page-head">
<?php 
/* back page link */
tmpl_back_link();
do_action('after_directory_header'); /*do action for display the breadcrumb in between header and container. */
do_action('directory_before_container_breadcrumb');
?>
</div>
<?php 
if ( is_active_sidebar('listingcategory_listing_above_content') ) : ?>
<div class="filters">
<div id="sidebar-primary" class="sidebar">
<?php dynamic_sidebar('listingcategory_listing_above_content'); ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php  endif; ?>
<div class="view_type_wrap">
<?php /*do action to display the breadcrumb  inside the container. */

/* Archive page title */
do_action('directory_before_archive_title'); ?>              
<h1 class="loop-title">
<?php echo ucfirst(apply_filters('tevolution_archive_page_title','Listing'));?>     
</h1>
<?php
if($archive_description[CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_LISTING]['description'] !=''){
?>
<div class="archive-meta"><?php echo $archive_description[CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_LISTING]['description']; ?></div>
<?php 
}
do_action('directory_after_archive_title');  
do_action('directory_before_loop_archive');
?>

</div>

<div id="content" class="contentarea large-9 small-12 columns <?php directory_class();?>">

<!--Start loop archive page-->  
<div id="loop_listing_taxonomy" class="search_result_listing <?php if($tmpdata['default_page_view']=="gridview"){echo 'grid';}else{echo 'list';}?>" <?php if( is_plugin_active('Tevolution-Directory/directory.php') && $tmpdata['default_page_view']=="mapview"){ echo 'style="display: none;"';}?>>
<?php if (have_posts()) : 
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
do_action('directory_before_post_loop');?>

<div class="post <?php templ_post_class();?>" >  
<?php 
/* Hook to display before image */  
do_action('tmpl_before_category_page_image');

/* Hook to Display Listing Image  */
do_action('directory_category_page_image');

/* Hook to Display After Image  */                       
do_action('tmpl_after_category_page_image'); 

/* Before Entry Div  */ 
do_action('directory_before_post_entry');?> 

<!-- Entry Start -->
<div class="entry"> 

<?php  /* do action for before the post title.*/ 
do_action('directory_before_post_title');         ?>
<div class="listing-wrapper">
<!-- Entry title start -->
<div class="entry-title">

<?php do_action('templ_post_title');                /* do action for display the single post title */?>

</div>

<?php do_action('directory_after_post_title');          /* do action for after the post title.*/?>

<!-- Entry title end -->

<!-- Entry details start -->
<div class="entry-details">

<?php  /* Hook to get Entry details - Like address,phone number or any static field  */  
do_action('listing_post_info');   ?>     

</div>
<!-- Entry details end -->
</div>
<!--Start Post Content -->
<?php /* Hook for before post content . */ 

do_action('directory_before_post_content'); 

/* Hook to display post content . */ 
do_action('templ_taxonomy_content');

/* Hook for after the post content. */
do_action('directory_after_post_content'); 
?>
<!-- End Post Content -->
<?php 
/* Hook for before listing categories     */
do_action('directory_before_taxonomies');

/* Display listing categories     */
do_action('templ_the_taxonomies'); 

/* Hook to display the listing comments, add to favorite and pinpoint   */                      
do_action('directory_after_taxonomies');?>
</div>
<!-- Entry End -->
<?php do_action('directory_after_post_entry');?>
</div>
<?php do_action('directory_after_post_loop');
endwhile; 
wp_reset_query();
else:?>
<p class='nodata_msg'><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found for the requested archive.', 'templatic' ); ?></p>              
<?php endif;
if($wp_query->max_num_pages !=1):?>
<div id="listpagi">
<div class="pagination pagination-position">
<?php if(function_exists('pagenavi_plugin')) { pagenavi_plugin(); } ?>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
</div>


<!--End loop archive page -->
</div>

</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct code for your condition and will work fine. You have to close the brace for the condition. Check this for condition reference [click here](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

```
<?php
            if ( is_bbpress() ) {
                get_template_part('archive-forum'); 
            } else {
                // continue with the current template code   
            } 
            get_footer(); 
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using brackets, you do not need to use `endif;` This whole `endif;` and opening `<?php` and closing `?>` in every row is very ugly.  `<!--` not valid in PHP code. And you need to add `;` after `get_template_part('archive-forum');`

```
<?php
    if ( is_bbpress() ) {
       get_template_part('archive-forum'); 
    } else {
       //Continue with the current template code

    }
    get_footer(); 
?>
 <!-- More none php code here. If there are no more php code, you can leave ?> -->
```

Comment: It doesn't quite working.. I'm really struggling with php. When I insert the code of the full template between { and } in else statement, I'm getting the blank page again. But if I output just echo 'hello world', it's showing properly. So I'm guessing I cannot just paste the template code?

Comment: Maybe you have syntax errors in your page. Add at very top of your file these 2 lines: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`